# How to have the return value of a lambda function as a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, lambda

Here is my code

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

timezones = {
    'GMT': lambda t: datetime.now(pytz.timezone(t)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d - %H:%M:%S")
}

for k, v in timezones:
    print(v(k))
```

What I want is to have a dictionary where the current time is the value for the timezone key.

When I try to do `for k, v in timezones:` I get: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I assume this is because there are two colons, which python interprets as having three values instead of two.

Any way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the values of the dictionary to be the lambda functions themselves?

Comment: No, I want the value to be what the lambda functions evaluate to :)

Comment: you need to do for `k,v in timezones.items()`

Comment: Ah of course it was something simple... thank you @Alexander :)